# Getting img url from RSS feed swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift, rss

I want to be able to retrieve the img url from a piece of string.

Here's a sample of the img URL that I'm trying to retrieve:

```
<p><img width="357" height="500" src="http://images.sgcafe.net/2015/05/OVA1-357x500.jpg" class="attachment-         medium wp-post-image" alt="OVA1" />
```

My current implemention is crashing at `textCheck` which says its `NIL`. I looked over at the Objective C solution on stackoverflow and implemented it in swift, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var elementString = item.summary
var regex: NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "img     src=\"([^\"]*)\"", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!
let range = NSMakeRange(0, count(elementString))
var textCheck = regex.firstMatchInString(elementString, options: nil, range: range)!
let text = (elementString as NSString).substringWithRange(textCheck.rangeAtIndex(1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consume as many characters up to the `src` attribute as possible. You can do it with `.*?`:

```
var regex: NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<img.*?src=\"([^\"]*)\"", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: nil)!
```

Also, you can use the sample from [Ross' iOS Swift blog](http://iosswift.tumblr.com/post/91218611429/a-simpler-regex-expression-syntax)

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func firstMatchIn(string: NSString!, atRangeIndex: Int!) -> String {
        var error : NSError?
        let re = NSRegularExpression(pattern: self, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
        let match = re.firstMatchInString(string, options: .WithoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length))
        return string.substringWithRange(match.rangeAtIndex(atRangeIndex))
    }
}
```

And in your calling code:

```
var result = "<img.*?src=\"([^\"]*)\"".firstMatchIn(elementString, atRangeIndex: 1)
```

To make sure `.` matches newline, use `options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators`.