# How can i get "src" string from RSS in Swift?

Tags: swift, regex, rss, nsregularexpression

I have the RSS page with the html tag like this:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
 <a href='https://www.24h.com.vn/bong-da/psg-trao-than-dong-mbappe-sieu-luong-bong-chi-kem-messi-real-vo-mong-c48a1112120.html' title='PSG trao tháº§n Ä‘á»“ng Mbappe siĂªu lÆ°Æ¡ng bá»•ng: Chá»‰ kĂ©m Messi, Real vá»¡ má»™ng'><img width='130' height='100' src='https://image.24h.com.vn/upload/4-2019/images/2019-12-27/1577463916-359-thumbnail.jpg' alt='PSG trao tháº§n Ä‘á»“ng Mbappe siĂªu lÆ°Æ¡ng bá»•ng: Chá»‰ kĂ©m Messi, Real vá»¡ má»™ng' title='PSG trao tháº§n Ä‘á»“ng Mbappe siĂªu lÆ°Æ¡ng bá»•ng: Chá»‰ kĂ©m Messi, Real vá»¡ má»™ng' /></a><br />PSG trong ná»— lá»±c giá»¯ chĂ¢n â€œsĂ¡t thá»§â€ Kylian Mbappe, sáºµn sĂ ng tÄƒng lÆ°Æ¡ng khá»•ng lá»“ - má»™t Ä‘á»™ng thĂ¡i nháº±m xua Ä‘uá»•i Real Madrid.
]]>
</description>
```

Please help me how can i get the value of `src` to show the image. I also try [Getting img url from RSS feed swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999974/getting-img-url-from-rss-feed-swift) but it doesn't work. Here is my code to get src (the code always run to `image = "nil"`):

```
let regex: NSRegularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<img.*?src=\"([^\"]*)\"", options: .caseInsensitive)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, description.count)
if let textCheck = regex.firstMatch(in: description, options: .withoutAnchoringBounds, range: range) {
    let text = (description as NSString).substring(with: textCheck.range(at: 1))
    image = text
} else {
    image = "nil"
}
```

Thank for your helping !

Comment: Obligatory [you can't parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3141234). Well actually, you can, in limited cases, but not generally. You always run into edge cases and bugs, and it's an all-around frustrating time. I would suggest you just use an HTML parser (like SwiftSoup), use it to parse the document, and just extract your `src` attribute's value from there.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, *`XML`, not `HTML`. Both `RSS` and `HTML` are `XML`-based formats, but `RSS` **is not** `HTML`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: i already parse the data successfully. I use FeedKit library. My issue is that i can not get the value of src

Comment: @user28434 if you want to get real technical about it, it's applicable to [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language), of which HTML was a variant (until recently). But most people don't know that (and shouldn't have to), and OP was talking about HTML, so I focused on HTML.

Comment: @TrungNguyen Parsing out attributes should be a feature of the parsing library. I'm not familiar with FeedKit or its API, but you should look into it, it probably already has something to do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your regex to be able to match single-quotes as well, not just double quotes, since the html string you're trying to parse contains single quotes, not double quotes like the one in the linked Q&A.

```
let regex: NSRegularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<img.*?src=[\"\']([^\"\']*)[\"\']", options: .caseInsensitive)
```

If you are sure you only need to match single quotes, you can simplify the pattern by replacing `[\"\']` with `\'`. Currently, the regex pattern will match both single and double quotes.

Comment: NB: This is one of the edge cases I was referring to, in my comment to the main post